# Tether-like tokens

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Is it possible to create a token with properties similar to tether? Specifically, we want to be able to control total number of tokens in circulation by:

- whenever new tokens are ordered we could add them,
- if n tokens are sent to a specific wallet to redeem their value (being paid by fiat currency) the tokens are distroyed

If at all possible, how should this be approached?

Comment: It should be possible. I'd start learning some solidity, perhaps doing the [Ethernaut](https://ethernaut.zeppelin.solutions). Then take a look a [OpenZeppelin contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity) to learn how real world contracts work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the contracts by [OpenZeppelin](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity), more specifically;

- [Mintable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/MintableToken.sol) for adding new tokens on demand
- [Burnable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BurnableToken.sol) for destroying them

These have been well tested, audited and adhere to security best practices. You can create your own token contract, which implements both of these to cover your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you will face is automation. You can quite easily get a contract with functions for minting/burning tokens but if you want to automate the process, you need an oracle to get information from outside.

So if you're ok with manually issuing minting/burning commands to the contract, then that's quite easy with the links you were given in different answer.

Comment: Is it possible to create a contract that can mint tokens on-demand? Or will the gas for those transactions be too expensive?